# Recreate Find on page browser function in a webview

Tags: android, webview, find

I'm trying to recreate the "Find on page" function found in the android web browser so I can apply it to my webview.

Does anyone know a good place for me to start looking or any hints?

So far I have:

```
webView . findAll ("something");
try
{
Method m = WebView.class.getMethod ("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
m.invoke ( webView , true);
}
catch (Throwable ignored)
{
Log.i ("Error", ignored.toString ());
}
```

But it only allows for a predefined search. The browser allows you to type in something to search for.

I'm hoping there is some example to work off of. I can't imagine I'm the first to want to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code already allows for a predefined search, all you need to do is get input from the user, and use the resulting String in place of the `"something"` in your example.

Here's one possible method, using an AlertDialog:
http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-user-input-with-an-alertdialog

Comment: this is just what I needed!  Worked like fresh muffins,  thank you!

Comment: In a Suggested Edit, "user1786360" recommended the following Javascript for finding text on a webpage. I have NOT checked this -- just passing it on. : http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/find.htm

Answer (score 3):

showFindDialog works great but only for Android 3.x. Apparently, it doesn't work for android 4.x... 
For Android 2.x, use findall()

Answer (score 1):

If you use showFindDialog(queryString, true); on your webview all is done for you.